# Deploy GNUStep application on windows machine

Tags: objective-c, windows, gcc, gnustep

I've an application written in objective-c with foundation framework, and it does not have any UI components. i build the application using GNUStep and GCC.
Now i want to deploy the application on another windows machine which is not having GNUStep installed, how can i do that.
is it possible to set GNUStep environment by coping the respective dlls.